# Python - pandas export to csv or dat file removing None or numpy.nan

Tags: python, pandas, null

When exporting a dataframe df to a dat file, how to remove the None or numpy.nan in the file? I just need an empty value.

```
df.to_csv('test.dat')
```

I have tried:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

or

```
df = df.replace(numpy.nan, '') and df = df.replace(None, '')
```

But I still see 'None' or 'nan' in the csv or dat file.

Comment: `df.dropna(how = 'any')` then `df.to_csv('test.dat')`

Comment: I do NOT want to drop the columns and rows.

Comment: df2 = df.dropna(axis=1, how='any')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the parameter

> na_rep : string, default ” Missing data representation"

and set this to ""

which you can read here:

[pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

This is the code:

```
file=pd.DataFrame({"one":[1,2,None,3,4],"two":[5,6,7,np.nan,8]})

file.to_csv("xxxxxxx",na_rep="")
```

Will lead to:
[image: Result]

Comment: Setting na_rep='' still returns 'None' or 'nan' in the csv or dat file.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my own question:

```
df = df.replace('None','')
df = df.replace('nan','')
```

It is clear that somehow pandas treat None and numpy.nan as string value here. Not sure why but this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Answering here to comment on what the [OP mentioned in his accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834197/1379826) in case others stumble upon this.

`"It is clear that somehow pandas treat None and numpy.nan as string value here. Not sure why but this solution works.`"
This is not true, and what happened was that either the columns of the original df were set strings, or only the "None" and "Nan" values were set as strings. Otherwise, the [first_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44832489/1379826) would work with `.replace(np.nan,'')`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'na_string':[1,2,'nan'],
    'na':[1,2,np.nan],
    'none_string':[1,2,'None'],
    'none':[1,2,None],
    'na_float':[1.1,1.2,np.nan],
    'mixed':[1.1,1.2,'nan']})
df
```

[image]

```
df.dtypes
#na_string       object
#na             float64
#none_string     object
#none           float64
#na_float       float64
#mixed           object
#dtype: object
```

Now note that when the column is  classified as `object`, all `na` and `None` are not identified as `np.nan` since they are strings.

[image]

And when you export them with `df.to_csv(path+'out.csv', na_rep='', index=False)`, even with the `na_rep`, all strings are kept, but not the actual `np.nan` or other null values.

[image]

If you had replaced your strings by `np.nan` you could've gotten there too:

```
df.replace('None',np.nan, inplace=True)
df.replace('nan',np.nan, inplace=True)
df.to_csv(path+'out2.csv', na_rep='', index=False)
```

[image]